# How to write DRY flash messages for ajax requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

What is the best (i.e, most maintainable, DRY) way to display a message to the user after an ajax request?

Obviously, the easiest way to achieve this for a single JS controller action is simply to use the associated JS partial. e.g.,

```
#create.js
$('.flash-container').html('<p>SUCCESS!</p>');
```

But, if the app contains a large number of ajaxed actions, this quickly becomes unmaintainable, requiring many partials to be updated if changes need to be made.

The approach I'm currently using is below. But this always seems very brittle and 'hacky' - I must be overlooking the Rails convention?

This is returning `That page doesn't exist!` the first time an ajax request is triggered on the page. All subsequent requests return the expected result until the page is reloaded. What is going on?

```
#my_controller.rb
def create
  if @object.save
    format.js   { flash[:notice] =  t('.notice') }
  else 
    format.js   { flash[:error] =  t('.error') }
  end
end
# application_controller.rb
after_action :flash_to_headers
def flash_to_headers
  return unless request.xhr?
  response.headers['X-Message'] = flash_message
  response.headers["X-Message-Type"] = flash_type.to_s
  flash.discard 
end
def flash_message
  [:alert, :error, :notice, :success].each do |type|
    return flash[type] unless flash[type].blank?
  end
  return nil
end

def flash_type
  [:alert, :error, :notice, :success].each do |type|
    return type unless flash[type].blank?
  end
  return :empty
end

#flash.js.coffee

$(document).ajaxComplete (event, request) ->

  msg   = request.getResponseHeader("X-Message")
  type  = request.getResponseHeader("X-Message-Type")

  if msg
    alert(msg)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not change your js partial to a js.erb partial and embed the message you want to send before it is parsed into standard js instead of sending through the header?

in the same way you can have .html.erb files you can also have .js.erb files:

```
# create.js.erb
<% if flash[:notice] %>
$('.flash-container').html('<p><%= flash[:notice] %></p>');
<% end %>
```

in terms of keeping it maintainable and dry, that is just down to code design, create a shared js.erb partial that you render inside other .js.erb parials:

```
#shared/_ajax_messages.js.erb
<% if flash[:notice] %>
$('.flash-container').html('<p><%= flash[:notice] %></p>');
<% end %>
<% if flash[:error] %>
$('.flash-container').html('<p><%= flash[:error] %></p>');
<% end %>

# create.js.erb
<%= render(partial: 'ajax_messages') %>
```

create a shared helper_method in a top-level controller:

```
# some_controller.rb
helper_method :handle_ajax_messages

# create.js.erb
$('.flash-container').html('<p><%= handle_ajax_messages %></p>');
```

You could extract a ServiceObject handler, or a factory if your into [DDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design)  to create custom NoticeObjects or Value Objects with `#to_html` `#to_js` `#to_json` etc methods to keep things DRY for all types of requests. There are a huge variety of other options and ways to keep code DRY and maintainable if you break out of some so-called "Rails conventions".

Comment: thanks for this extensive answer. your first suggestion still requires `ajax_messages` to be manually inserted into every JS partial. But if I want "ajaxified messages" to be the default for any actions that currently exist or may be added in the future, is the header the best way to go? And if so, why am I getting this odd `That page doesn't exist!` the first time a request is sent?

Comment: DDD may possibly be what I'm looking for. Can you suggest any basic rails examples/ tutorials that would help me better visualise how to implement this approach?

Comment: indeed the first section was just to explain, that you can use embedded ruby with the js files, which then opens them up to your whole ruby code base allowing for you to DRY it up in any way you wish. Im not sure why you are getting the page doesn't exist error, and in terms of the header, while it may be a viable approach, I wouldn't personally use it. DDD however I would strongly recommend, as it allows you to create DRY reusable code so easily that can be easily adapted and reused in almost any case when designed right, as I mentioned above I would create translatable Value Objects. links:

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design   https://www.slideshare.net/dwhelan/domain-driven-design-and-hexagonal-srchitecture-with-rails    http://reevoo.github.io/blog/2014/07/28/ddd-with-ruby/   http://rubyblog.pro/2017/07/solid-dependency-inversion-principle

Comment: also another thing to think about is to not use js requests at all, but to instead move over to something more similar to a JSON api call, removing the 'view' element all together, allowing you to create a more RESTful approach, which can still be implemented nicely using DDD.